# Android Studio Leanback Hiding Status Bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv, leanback

I'm working on an Android TV app. By default it uses the Leanback theme. When the app runs on a device there is no status bar, obviously because it's a TV. However when designing the .xml's in Android Studio on the Render Screen the status bar is shown which makes it hard to work out positioning.

Is there a way to hide the status bar in the Render screen in Android Studio while using Leanback theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `android:windowFullscreen` to your theme, for example:

```
<style name="Theme.Example.Leanback" parent="Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/fade</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/fade</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/search_opaque</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and then select `Example.Leanback` from the theme selector.

Comment: Yeah I have that selected, but it's still showing the status bar with Wifi signal and time on the Rendered. http://i.imgur.com/IlYDOrA.png

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question. I just changed my answer.

Comment: Is something like this also available for the app bar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296436/alternative-for-missing-app-bar-in-android-tv